# Use conditional formatting to highlight rows where every cell is empty

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to check my spreadsheet to make sure that each row in a certain range of columns has one cell that is not empty. If a row does not have one cell with an entry, I want the whole row to get highlighted. Then I'll be able to easily spot the rows that need to have an entry.

Specifically, the entries are all going to be numbers – in case that matters.

I tried a few conditional formatting rules but they were spectacular failures.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for

> If a row does not have one cell with an entry, I want the whole row to get highlighted. Then I'll be able to easily spot the rows that need to have an entry.

Try the following formula

```
=COLUMNS($A2:$F2)<>COUNTA($A2:$F2)
```

[image]